# JSon not fetching data

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, httprequest

I have included my entire code here. For some reason it doesn't enter class JsonHandler and hence I'm unable to fetch the required data. I can't seem to understand the problem here. Could be something really silly.

I've checked by using the help of a toast that it does not enter the Json Handler class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button prem,work,tshirt,tech,ntech,query,reg,about;
String[] name,org,desc,date,time,loc,cname1,cname2,pho1,pho2,email,team,fee;
int k;
int[] tid,ftid;
String[] fname,forg,fdesc,fdate,ftime,floc,fcname1,fcname2,fpho1,fpho2,femail,fteam,ffee;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new request().execute();



    prem=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    about=(Button) findViewById (R.id.babout);
    tshirt=(Button) findViewById (R.id.btshirt);
    work=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);
    tech=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
    ntech=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button5);
    reg=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
    query=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button6);
    prem.setOnClickListener(this);
    about.setOnClickListener(this);
    tshirt.setOnClickListener(this);
    work.setOnClickListener(this);
    tech.setOnClickListener(this);
    ntech.setOnClickListener(this);
    reg.setOnClickListener(this);
    query.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.babout:



    break;

    case R.id.btshirt:

        break;

    case R.id.button1:


        break;

    case R.id.button2:

        break;

    case R.id.button3:

        break;

    case R.id.button4:

        break;

    case R.id.button5:


        break;

    case R.id.button6:

        break;

    }
    //Events o = null;
    //o.set(ftid, fname, fdate, ffee, fcname1, fcname2, fpho1, fpho2, floc, forg, fdesc, femail, fteam, ftime);
}


private boolean isOnline() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netinfo!=null && netinfo.isConnected();
}

private class request extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>{

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    AndroidHttpClient client= AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
    HttpGet request;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if (isOnline())
        {
            try{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                request = new HttpGet("www.com");

            }catch(NullPointerException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();}
            jsonhandler handler = new jsonhandler();
            try
            {
                return client.execute(request,handler);
            }catch(ClientProtocolException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
      {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (this.client != null) {
          this.client.close();
        }
      }

}
private class jsonhandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>>{
@Override
public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    //List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String jsonresponse = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    int i;
    JSONArray data;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json Enter", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        data = new JSONArray(jsonresponse);
        for(i=0;i<data.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
            name[i]=obj.get("name").toString();
            org[i]=obj.get("organisation").toString();
            desc[i]=obj.getString("description").toString();
            date[i]=obj.get("date").toString();
            time[i]=obj.get("timings").toString();
            loc[i]=obj.get("location").toString();
            cname1[i]=obj.get("cname1").toString();
            pho1[i]=obj.get("cno1").toString();
            cname2[i]=obj.get("cname2").toString();
            pho2[i]=obj.get("cno2").toString();
            email[i]=obj.get("email").toString();
            team[i]=obj.get("team").toString();
            tid[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.get("tid").toString());
            fee[i]=obj.get("fee").toString();


        }
        k=i;
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
}
```

Error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$jsonhandler.handleResponse(MainActivity.java:269)
at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$jsonhandler.handleResponse(MainActivity.java:1)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:273)
at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$request.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:240)
at com.example.gravitas2015.MainActivity$request.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: Any error ? stacktrace ? url you are using ? there is a catch block above the handler call...do you get any error before ?

Comment: No errors. Just that the strings I stored the date to were still empty

Comment: Sorry. I do have an error
Will update now

Comment: ok...its beacuse you are calling the Toast's method from your background thread...Toast method and other UI stuffs are part of UI thread which must be called from there or you can call UI stuff from onPostExecute which is called in UI thread...some more details here https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Still can't fetch the data. Crashes when i try to print name[0]
Getting a NPE. Must mean I never got any data into it right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show Toast message in background thread. Remove the code below and try again.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json Enter", 
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Still can't fetch the data. Crashes when i try to print name[0]
Getting a NPE. Must mean I never got any data into it right?